# Delete all words starting with the same letter in a binary tree

Tags: c, tree

I have a function that deletes all words starting with the same first letter in a avl binary tree(letter is given by user).

```
node_t* delete_from_tree(node_t* root, char search, int *deleted)
{
    int cmp;
    node_t* new_node = NULL;
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    else
    {
        cmp = root->data[0] - search; 
        if (cmp == 0)
        {
            *deleted += 1;
            new_node = delete_node(root, root->data);
            return delete_from_tree(root, search, deleted);
        }
        else if (cmp > 0)
        {
            new_node = delete_from_tree(root->left, search, deleted);
        }
        else
        {
            new_node =  delete_from_tree(root->right, search, deleted);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

It deletes the words from tree but i cannot understand why unnecessary characters are printing when i call tree traversal.

```
void print_inorder(node_t* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    print_in(node->left);
    printf("%s ", node->data);  
    print_in(node->right);
}
```

Example: words in a tree: life, value, administation, advantage, add, son.

Expected output:
life, son, value.

Real output:
{t  life, son, value.

Comment: There's not enough code here to see where the problem is.  What's the definition of `delete_node` and `delete_from_root`?  How is the tree populated?  How is the tree printed?

Comment: Hm, `return delete_from_tree(root, search, deleted);` looks somewhat wrong, since `root` has already been deleted... Should that by chance be `return delete_from_tree(new_node, search, deleted);` and `return new_node;` at the end?

Comment: In `else if (cmp > 0)`, why does code save the result of `delete_from_tree(root->left, search, deleted);` in `new_node`?  It is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This is not a definite answer, but it's too long for a comment space.

You didn't show what `new_node = delete_node(root, root->data);` does to the tree structure, but most probably it deletes the node pointed at by the `root` variable.

If so, the `root` pointer becomes invalid on the return from `delete_node()`, hence the recursive call in the `return` statement

```
return delete_from_tree(root, search, deleted);
```

makes the called function to operate on a non-`NULL`, anyway *invalid* `root` pointer.